# Undefined is not an object in React Native

Tags: react-native

Hi ninjas quick question I have a button which runs the following

`onPress={this.props.productStore.closeModal}`

but if I change the code to have a function:

`closeModal() {
    this.props.productStore.closeModal;
//alert('close modal');
   }`

and the button trigger `onPress={this.closeModal}` I get undefined is not an object. (`this.props.productStore.closeModal` is a mobx store which updates isModalVisible to false). If I uncomment alert in closeModal function the alert runs fine. Any help with resolving is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second variant, `this.props` is undefined because the function `closeModal` is not bound to this. Use either the arrow function syntax like below:

```
closeModal = () => {
  this.props.productStore.closeModal();
}
```

or bind the function to this.

```
onPress={this.closeModal.bind(this)}
```

Another problem that I noticed in the code is you are not calling the function. You should call the function.

```
this.props.productStore.closeModal();
```